# Primefaces confirmDialog doesn't show up after one call

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a problem with PrimeFaces `<p:confirmDialog>`, when I click on the `<p:commandLink>` that must show up the dialog and choose 'No', everything is fine. But when I click on yes,everything works just the first time.
When the process is over and I click again on any `<p:commandLink>`, the dialog doesn't show up unless I refresh the whole page.I had try everything but I cannot figure out what can be the problem.

```
<h:form>
   <p:dataTable  border="0" rules="all" value="#{userBean.users}" var="user" autoUpdate="true" styleClass="table table-hover" paginator="true" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" rowsPerPageTemplate="6,10,15" >
      <p:column>
         <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Login" />
         </f:facet>
         <h:outputText value="#{user.login}" />
      </p:column>
      <p:column>
         <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="" />
         </f:facet>
         <p:commandLink class="badge bg-red marge-left"  onclick='PF("cdu#{user.id}").show()' title="Supprimer un utilisateur"><span class="fa fa-trash-o"/></p:commandLink>
         <p:confirmDialog ajax="true" message="Voulez vous vraiment supprimer l'utilisateur '#{user.login}'" closable="true"  header="Confirmation" severity="alert" widgetVar="cdu#{user.id}"  >
            <p:commandButton  value="oui" actionListener="#{userBean.deleteUser}"  update="@form" onclick='PF("cdu#{user.id}").hide()' styleClass="btn btn-primary"/>
            <p:commandButton  value="non" onclick='PF("cdu#{user.id}").hide()' type="button" styleClass="btn btn-danger" />
         </p:confirmDialog>
      </p:column>
   </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Is the `p:datatable` relevant? Meaning, if you remove it and have a single field, it works? And did you compare with the PF showcase/documentation examples? Did you get one of those working correctly? And what about ajax="true" on the confirmDialog? Such an attribute does not exist. Or did you try experimenting with the 'update="@form"? e.g. removing it, or putting it on the commandLink. (Sorry, I have no time to experiment, so I'm just giving hints). It sounds like things I've read before, but cannot immediately pinpoint it.

Comment: I use p:datatable because I want to paginate thelist of users.I've tried to use the confirmDialog on the showcase/documentation but it doesn't work.So i tried with this and everything was fine.You're right for the ajax attribute, i put it  when i was testing the update @form but i forgot to remove it.

Comment: I'm not saying it is not relevant in the real world case, but is it relevant in playing a part in this problem?

Comment: I think dat yes because if you have noticed, every column of the datatable has its own confirmDialog with an id based on the field of my model  user.id.

Comment: Think or are sure? Tried it? If it works without a datatable, and does not work with, at least not in this way, that is important informtion.

Comment: If I remove the datatable, I won't be able to paginate my list unless I use pure jquery or javascript:-( ,I also use datamodel in my bean to easily retrieve selected row after a button's click, so i must iterate with a datatable(jsf or primefaces). Notice that I already use this confirmDialog inside a datatable in this same way in another project and everything  was fine.

Comment: PLEASE... I'm not saying you should remove it at all for a production version... nor start using any jquery or whatever. Just to test if in this case it makes a difference. And I **can't** notice you use it in another project in the same way (not clairvoyant). But if it works there. Find the differences and fix those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had finally resolved my problem. I changed the `<p:confirmDialog>` by a global one and it works.

```
<h:form>
   <p:dataTable  border="0" rules="all" value="#{userBean.users}" var="user" autoUpdate="true" styleClass="table table-hover">
      <p:column>
         <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Login" />
         </f:facet>
         <h:outputText value="#{user.login}" />
      </p:column>
      <p:column>
         <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Nom" />
         </f:facet>
         <h:outputText value="#{user.firstName} #{user.lastName}" />
      </p:column>
      <p:column style="width:200px;">
         <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Email" />
         </f:facet>
         <h:outputText value="#{user.email}" />
      </p:column>
      <p:column >
         <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="" />
         </f:facet>
         <p:commandLink class="badge bg-blue marge-left" action="#{userBean.getUserRowToEdit}" title="Editer un utilisateur" ><span class="fa fa-edit"/></p:commandLink>
         <p:commandLink class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash icon-trash"  actionListener="#{userBean.deleteUser}"  title="Supprimer un utilisateur"  update="@form">
            <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Voulez-vous vraiment supprimer l'utilisateur?" icon="ui-icon-alert"/>
         </p:commandLink>
      </p:column>
   </p:dataTable>
   <p:confirmDialog global="true">
      <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check"/>
      <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
   </p:confirmDialog>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and repaired it a little. Hope it will work for you too.
-I removed `ajax="true"`
-`usersBean.deleteUser` function need to know which user to so -> delete`usersBean.deleteUser(user)`

Under is my code that i use to test your case. A few things are changed due to existing beans i have. This code is tested on latest primefaces(5.2).

my xhtml file:

```
         <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="" />
            </f:facet>

            <p:commandLink class="badge bg-red marge-left" value="delete" onclick='PF("cdu#{user.userId}").show()' title="Supprimer un utilisateur"><span class="fa fa-trash-o"/></p:commandLink>

            <p:confirmDialog message="Voulez vous vraiment supprimer l'utilisateur '#{user.name}'" closable="true"  header="Confirmation" severity="alert" widgetVar="cdu#{user.userId}"  >        
                <p:commandButton  value="oui" actionListener="#{loginBean.deleteUser(user)}"  update="@form" onclick='PF("cdu#{user.userId}").hide()' styleClass="btn btn-primary"/>  
                <p:commandButton  value="non" onclick='PF("cdu#{user.userId}").hide()' type="button" styleClass="btn btn-danger" />   
            </p:confirmDialog> 
         </p:column>

     </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

my loginBean:
       public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6188046073588310656L;

private List<User> users= new ArrayList<User>();

public LoginBean() {

}

public List<User> getUsers() {
    if(users.size()==0){
        for (int i= 0; i<3; i++){
            User u = new User();
            u.setUserId(i);
            u.setName("noob"+i);
            users.add(u);
        }
    }
    return users;
}

public void deleteUser(User user){
    users.remove(user);
}
}
```